# what does "((class)obj).method()" do?

Tags: java, casting

i saw the above code in one of my assignments and couldn't find any information about it. Would someone please explain what it means?

`obj` would be an instance of the class `class` and `method` is a method of this object.

Why is `class.obj.method` wrong?

I tried searching topics related to type-conversion which didn't deliver the answer that I'm looking for. I don't know how to research something like this. Any tips on this are welcome.

Comment: (class)x is a cast operator ... it casts the object reference x into the type class (or throws a cast exception).  The outer parans are needed for order of operations.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it really class and not Class? class with a lower case c is a reserved word: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: you can also just name it ((Hello)world).helloworld() .in that case Hello is your class, world is the instance of it and helloworld would be the method. so they didn't use any reserved words in that assignment.

Comment: What is the problem?  What is it that makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: it wasn't clear for me that "((class)obj).method()" and "class.obj.method" are intended for different things. i now know that i need a deeper understanding of typecasting. thanks!

Comment: @RossDrew: you cannot use the word class (all in lower case) as the name of a class. It is forbidden by the Java specs. That's why (class)obj is not possible, whereas (Class)obj is.

Comment: @Burkhard he's not talking about using class as a classname, but indicating that the classname goes in that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [type casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) from a type to another type and when you are forced to do it it's because it's a down cast, so a conversion to a narrower type. Assume the following:

```
Base base = new Derived();
base.derivedMethod(); // compilation error: base is statically a Base
((Derived)base).derivedMethod(); // no compilation error and you are able to call a method of Derived on the object
```

Upcasts are implicit (a `Derived` is already a `Base`) while down casts must be explicited.

Since the downcast is the only operation which removes strong type safety from your program (you are asking to the type checker to not follow type checking when you do the cast), you should avoid using them when you can.

Of course casting an object to a type which is not contained in the object's hierarchy tree is wrong a will lead to a runtime error (namely a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html))

Answer (score 4):

Assumes `obj` is an instance of `class` (although I suspect you meant `Class` with an uppercase C) then calls a method on it called `method()`

```
((Class)obj) //Casts obj into a Class object
((Class)obj).method() //calls a method in obj (which is now in a Class object)
```

Comment: To be specific, it doesn't put anything. It is casting the object to the given type.